# NestJS - Use service inside Interceptor (not global interceptor)

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-jwt

I have a controller that uses custom interceptor:

Controller:

```js
@UseInterceptors(SignInterceptor)
    @Get('users')
    async findOne(@Query() getUserDto: GetUser) {
        return await this.userService.findByUsername(getUserDto.username)
    }
```

I have also I SignService, which is wrapper around NestJwt:

SignService module:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        JwtModule.registerAsync({
            imports: [ConfigModule],
            useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
                privateKey: configService.get('PRIVATE_KEY'),
                publicKey: configService.get('PUBLIC_KEY'),
                signOptions: {
                    expiresIn: configService.get('JWT_EXP_TIME_IN_SECONDS'),
                    algorithm: 'RS256',
                },
            }),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
    ],
    providers: [SignService],
    exports: [SignService],
})
export class SignModule {}
```

And Finally SignInterceptor:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SignInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        return next.handle().pipe(map(data => this.sign(data)))
    }

    sign(data) {
        const signed = {
            ...data,
            _signed: 'signedContent',
        }

        return signed
    }
}
```

SignService works properly and I use it. I would like to use this as an interceptor
How can I inject SignService in to SignInterceptor, so I can use the functions it provides?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume that `SignInterceptor` is part of the `ApiModule`:

```
@Module({
  imports: [SignModule], // Import the SignModule into the ApiModule.
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [SignInterceptor],
})
export class ApiModule {}
```

Then inject the `SignService` into the `SignInterceptor`:

```
@Injectable()
export class SignInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private signService: SignService) {}

  //...
}
```

Because you use `@UseInterceptors(SignInterceptor)` to use the interceptor in your controller Nestjs will instantiate the `SignInterceptor` for you and handle the injection of dependencies.

Comment: Moments after I posted the question I did the same thing. In any case thanks. Answer accepted